# How to measure execution time for GUI applications like GIMP?

Tags: gui, gimp

For LibreOffice, I can measure the execution time thanks to `time` command line and the `--terminate_after_init` option of `libreoffice` command. But for GIMP and other GUI applications which do not have such option, how to measure the execution time? Thank you.

However, my example for LibreOffice is like below:

```
master@master:~$ time libreoffice --terminate_after_init

real    0m0.877s
user    0m0.400s
sys     0m0.117s
master@master:~$
```

Comment: Gimp has a "batch" mode.

Comment: Hi @xenoid, Im sorry I don't understand the batch mode and the online explanation https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/ does not help with my point in measuring the GUI application execution time. Could you please give me example command line? Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Complete example with execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430081/how-to-run-python-scripts-using-gimpfu-from-windows-command-line/44435560#44435560)

Comment: @xenoid that's worth either making it an answer or marking this as duplicate of the other question, tbh.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  The other question isn't really about execution times. Measuring the time taken is a by-product.